# React - how to extend a component that has child components and keep them?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I have `MyMenu` functional component which uses [`antd` Menu](https://ant.design/components/menu/)  with horizontal variation:

```
import React  from 'react'
import {Menu} from 'antd'

function MyMenu() {
    return (
        <Menu
            mode={'horizontal'}
        >
            <Menu.Item key='Home'>Home</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item key='SignUp'>Sign up</Menu.Item>
        </Menu>
    )
}
```

Now, what I wanna do is create a `HorizontalMenu` func.component that will be using `<Menu mode={'horizontal'}></Menu>` by default.

I've tried doing it like this:

```
function HorizontalMenu(props) {
    return (
        <Menu
            mode={'horizontal'}
        >
            {props.children}
        </Menu>
    )
}

function MyMenu() {
    return (
        <HorizontalMenu>
            <HorizontalMenu.Item key='Home'>Home</HorizontalMenu.Item>
            <HorizontalMenu.Item key='SignUp'>Sign up</HorizontalMenu.Item>
        </HorizontalMenu>
    )
}
```

But menu items just never get rendered..

**Edit**
After reading my own question it occurred to me that I can simply do

```
HorizontalMenu.Item = Menu.Item
```

and then everything works as expected.
But is it a *proper* way of doing that?

Comment: `HorizontalMenu` is a function that renders a Component `Menu`. Why do you call it using `Item` in the function `MyMenu`??

Comment: eh... I shouldn't use func.components in that scenario?..

Comment: Yes sorry my bad I didn't see the package `antd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because of you didn't declare the `HorizontalMenu.Item` component. You can simply use the `Menu.Item` component inside your `HorizontalMenu` component like so:

```
import React from "react";
import { Menu } from "antd";

function HorizontalMenu({ children, ...rest }) {
  return <Menu {...rest} mode="horizontal">{children}</Menu>;
}

function MyMenu() {
  return (
    <HorizontalMenu>
      <Menu.Item key="Home">Home</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item key="SignUp">Sign up</Menu.Item>
    </HorizontalMenu>
  );
}
```

However, if you'd like to use the `HorizontalMenu.Item` component. Then you have to define that component:

```
import React from "react";
import { Menu } from "antd";

function HorizontalMenuItem({ children, ...rest }) {
  return <Menu.Item {...rest}>{children}</Menu.Item>;
}

class HorizontalMenu extends React.Component {
  // Allow it to be accessiable through HorizontalMenu.Item
  static Item = HorizontalMenuItem;

  render() {
    const { children, ...rest } = this.props;

    return (
      <Menu {...rest} mode="horizontal">
        {children}
      </Menu>
    );
  }
}

function MyMenu() {
  return (
    <HorizontalMenu>
      <HorizontalMenu.Item key="Home">Home</HorizontalMenu.Item>
      <HorizontalMenu.Item key="SignUp">Sign Up</HorizontalMenu.Item>
    </HorizontalMenu>
  );
}
```

Note that I use the spread operator `<Menu {...rest} mode="horizontal">`, so you can still pass any other optionals props to the underlying `Menu` component.

Hope this helps.

Comment: special shout out for `{...rest}` syntax - was just thinking on how to do that ))